# UITableViewCell with different layouts of IBOutlets and different number of IBOutlets

Tags: uitableview, swift, layout, constraints

I am trying to do tableview with different cell styles. My first row's image is the largest one and has three labels. I need to set such constraints only for the first cell. The second, third, fourth rows have smaller image and the same quantity of labels. Other cells have only only labels with no image. So far I have this code:

```
class MainPageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var labelDateOfPublication: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var labelTitle: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var labelIntroText: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var imageMainPage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var contentViewMainCell: UIView!


override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


    imageMainPage.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    var constX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageMainPage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    imageMainPage.addConstraint(constX)


    var constY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageMainPage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    imageMainPage.addConstraint(constY)

    var constW = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageMainPage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 300)
    imageMainPage.addConstraint(constW)

}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

}

I am using this main cell here:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mainPage", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MainPageTableViewCell


    println(indexPath.row)
    cell.labelTitle.text = arrayMainPage[indexPath.row].pageTitle
    cell.labelIntroText.text = arrayMainPage[indexPath.row].introText
    cell.labelDateOfPublication.text = arrayMainPage[indexPath.row].pubDate

    var link = arrayMainPage[indexPath.row].linkToImage as String
    var imgCache = arrayMainPage[indexPath.row].imageDictionary
    //var imgCache = imageDictionary
    //println("print image aluew \(img?.)")
    if let img = imgCache[link]  {

        let image = CommonFunctions.vignettePhoto(img, imageViewLocal:cell.imageMainPage)

      //  cell.image.image = image

        println("it is not blank. index of array \(indexPath.row)")
    }else{
        CommonFunctions.loadImageAsync(link, imageView: cell.imageMainPage!, article: arrayMainPage[indexPath.row], viewContr: self)
        println("it is blank index of array \(indexPath.row)")
    }

    return cell
}
```

However, the constrains that I am adding are not working. I am planning to create three UITableViewCells with different constraints. Somehow I need to programatically set cell identity to the cell that I am using. Please , somebody tell me why my constraints are not working?

Comment: Constraints will work if you can add properly. You have to give sufficient number of constraints to satisfy constraints criteria.

Comment: ok, I thought to try simple constrains first. So, you think I need to add all constrains to image and labels ?

Comment: Suppose you want to place the image at left side and vertically center aligned, then you have to give leading space constraints and vertically center align constraints. These two will work perfect for image.

Comment: Not working!  I put this code:var constLeading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageMainPage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeadingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        imageMainPage.addConstraint(constLeading)

        
        var constY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageMainPage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        imageMainPage.addConstraint(constY)

Comment: Why don't you apply these constraints in storyboard itself.

Comment: I want to set this constrains programatically because these constrains are not static. I need three different constrtains